# SOM to loop in all the Sites of Site Collection

Tags: csom, jsom, ssom

I am new to sharepoint programming I have requirement to loop all the sites of site collection which should also loop  including sub-sites.

Can any one help me how can I do this via Server Object Model

Answer (score 1):

**Use `AllWebs` property to returns all the Web sites within a site collection, including the top-level site and all subsites.**

```
    using (SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site)
        {
            SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
            foreach(SPWeb owebsite in collWebsite)
            {
                string webTitle = owebsite.Title;
            }                
        }
```

**Use `Webs` property to return a list of all the first-tier subsites beneath a specific Web site**

```
    using (SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site)
        {                
            SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
            foreach (SPWeb owebsite in collWebsite)
            {
                string webTitle = owebsite.Title;
                foreach(SPWeb subweb in owebsite.Webs)
                {
                    string subwebTitle = subweb.Title;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try below code:

```
string webUrl = "http://Server/sites/SiteCollection";

using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite(webUrl).OpenWeb())
{
    SPWebCollection collWebsite = oWebsite.Webs;

    foreach (SPWeb subSite in collWebsite)
    {
        Label1.Text += SPEncode.HtmlEncode(subSite.Title) + "<BR>";
        subSite.Close();
    }
}
```

You could check below link for more details.

[How to: Enumerate Sites and Site Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462161(v=office.14).aspx)